# How to handle client downloading gzip served from Node.js server app?

Tags: node.js, http, xmlhttprequest, gzip

I have a question about handling a gzip response on my client side application. I would like the client's browser to pop up an alert "how do you want to handle?" download prompt.

My Node.js server is compressing my files into a gzip format then sending it with a HTTP write response. My client receives a HTTP 200 status although the size of the response is very small compared to my file and nothing doesn't populate my web app. I have anticipated the browser to handle this sort of response to a server sending gzip. similar to how gmail handles downloading files. Can you help me to see if I have missed anything?

server.js

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    if (request.url === '/download'){
        let data_zip = retrievedata()
        const scopedata_zip = ('./scopedata.txt.gz')
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip' });
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/javascript' });
        response.write(scopedata_zip);
    }
})           

var retrievedata = () =>{
    const gzip = zlib.createGzip();
    const inp = fs.createReadStream('scopedata.txt');
    const out = fs.createWriteStream('scopedata.txt.gz');
    inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
    return out
}
```

Client.js

```
var downloadData=()=>{
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'download', true);
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
xhr.setRequestHeader("Encoding", "null")
xhr.onload = function (){
    if(this.status == 200){
        let form = document.createElement("form");
        let element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        let response = this.responseText
        console.log(response)
        document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = 'download'
        document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = response;
        // document.getElementById("state").appendChild(form)
    }
}

xhr.onerror = function(err){
    console.log("request error...",err)
}

xhr.send()
```

}

The client is just populating my index div the response to, but nothing is received.

my gzip file is 327mb.
Chrome inspector network says this request is only 170B so I am not receiving my file.

Note `xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")` is commented out becuase I get this error: Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding". I have set it to null to allow the browser to handle this.

Any input on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have found the HTTP header `Content-Disposition` has to be set for the file to be handled as a attachment to download. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition] . Updating my server header as `response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=',file);` and my client request as `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=',file);`

Answer (score 1):

There were three things I was doing wrong. I managed to get the browser window by creating a new element, checking if the element has a download attribute and appending the `XHR.Response` as the location from the `href`. The second portion of my issue was not receiving the zip file with the appropriate request headers. Because my zip file was a larger size the browser handles the binary buffer stream as a blob. Read more about XHR response types [XHR.response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data). The other issue was on my server side which was using `fs.readFile` to read the zip as a buffer. Because my zip was made up of multiple files fs.readFile it would stop reading as it hit the end of the first file.

so my client code looks like

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = ' '
document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = ' ';
xhr.open('POST', 'download', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment')
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/zip"); //content-type must be set
xhr.setRequestHeader("Encoding", "null") //unsure of why I need this but it doesnt work with out it for me
xhr.responseType = "blob"; // This must be set otherwise the browser was interpretting the buffer stream as string instead of binary

xhr.onload = function (){
    if(this.status == 200){
        let form = document.createElement("form");
        let element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
        document.body.appendChild(form);

        let response = this.response // defined as blob above
        document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = 'download'
        document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = response;
        var blob = new Blob([response], {type: "application/zip"});
        var file = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        filename = 'Data.zip'
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        if ("download" in a) { //check if element can download
          a.href = file;
          a.download = filename;
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click(); //automatically browser download
          document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
}
```

Server side

```
else if (request.url === '/download'){
                    archiveZip((data)=>{ // using archivezip and adding a callback function to insert my routes XHR response
                        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
                        response.setHeader('Content-Length', data.length) // this is important header because without it the browser might truncate the entire response especially if there are end of file characters zipped up in the buffer stream
                        response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="Data.zip"');
                        response.end(data);
                    })

                }


var archiveZip = (callback) =>{
var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/Data.zip'); //output
var archive = archiver('zip', {zlib: { level: 9 }});

output.on('close', function() {
  console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
  console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
  fs.readFile('./Data.zip', function (err, content) {
                        if (err) {
                            response.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'})
                            console.log(err);
                            response.end("No such file");    
                        } else {
                            callback(content);
                        }
                    });
});

output.on('end', function() {
  console.log('Data has been drained');
});

archive.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});

archive.pipe(output);

// append a file
archive.file(data_files + '/parsed_scope.json', { name: 'parsed_scope.json' });
archive.file(data_files + '/scopedata_index.json', { name: 'scopedata_index.json' });
archive.file(data_files + '/scopedata.txt', { name: 'scopedata.txt' });
archive.finalize();
```

There are many zip libraries I was looking at ones that can handle zipping a directory with multiple files and went with [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver). I would have like to use the built in zlib that comes with node but only supports single small files.